# How to show that $hkh^{-1}\in K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of group $G$, and $HK=KH$, where $HK=\{hk:h\in H,k\in K\}$. How to show that, if $h\in H, k\in K$ then $hkh^{-1}\in K$?

I have done this: suppose $hkh^{-1}=c$, then $hk=ch$ and since $hk\in HK=KH$, we get $ch\in KH$, hence $c\in KH$. How to derive that $c\in K$ indeed?

Comment: Is K or H a normal subgroup?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Why are asking for help in proving something that is not true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the group $S_3$ then $S_3=HK$ where H is the subgroup generated by 3-cycles and $K$ is the subgroup generated by any 2-cycle. Then $K$ is not normal otherwise $S_3$ would be isomorphic to $Z_3×Z_2=an\ abelian\ group$,i.e. there exists $k\in K$ and $h\in H$ such that $hkh^{-1}\not \in K$.

Why $K$ is not normal in $S_3$ . If possible let $K$ is normal in $S_3$. Then consider the mapping $f:H×K\rightarrow S_3,f(h,k)=hk$. Note that $h_1h_2k_1k_2=h_1k_1h_2k_2$, since for any $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ with $k\not =identity$ implies that $hkh^{-1}=k$ ($|K|=2$ and $K$ is normal in $S_3$) i.e. $hk=kh$. Therefore $f$ is a group homomorphism. Now $H\cap K=\ trivial\ group$(a 2-cycle cannot be 3-cycle,vice versa) implies $f$ is injective and $|S_3|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ implies $HK=S_3$ i.e $f$ is surjective. Hence $ f$  is an isomorphism.

Comment: `Then K is not normal otherwise S3 would be isomorphic to Z3×Z2` -  can you please explain more?

Comment: @UserS Please help me with this particular statement in a solution that I have: "Let $H=\langle (1\,2\,3\,4),(2\,4)\rangle$ and $K=\langle(1\,2\,3)\rangle$ be subgroups of $S_4$. If $HK=KH$ then in particular $(1\,2\,3\,4)(1\,2\,3)(1\,4\,3\,2)=(2\,3\,4)\in K$, a contradiction; hence $HK\ne KH$. "  I don't get $$(1\,2\,3\,4)(1\,2\,3)(1\,4\,3\,2)=(2\,3\,4)\in K$$

Comment: @taritgoswami, there are only two groups of order 6 up to isomorphism: [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_6) might help.

Comment: @silent notice that $(1432)=(1234)^{-1}$

Comment: I know that! I can't see why $(1\,2\,3\,4)(1\,2\,3)(1\,2\,3\,4)^{-1}\in K$

Comment: If $\sigma$, $\gamma=(m_1\ m_2\ ......\ m_k)$ are two cycles of $S_n$ then $\sigma\  \gamma\ \sigma^{-1}=(\sigma(m_1)\ \sigma(m_2)\ .......\ \sigma(m_k))$. So that in particular according to informationas given in 2nd comment we have $(1234)(123)(1432)=(234)$ but notice that cycles of $K$ are permutation of 1,2,3.

Comment: I see why that conjugation gives $(2\,3\,4)$, what I can't see is why that should lie inside $K$. I also see why that leads to contradiction.

Comment: Only cycles of $K$ are $(123),(132),\ identity$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84616/discussion-between-silent-and-users).